# Php regular expression issue

Tags: php

This is my regular expression which accept only string and number characters..otherwise it's say "Only string charactes are allow. ex; a-z or 0-9".

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $uname) != 1
$err[] = "Only string charactes are allow. ex; a-z or 0-9";
```

But if i write a text with space like(text space) then it's say "Only string charactes are allow. ex; a-z or 0-9".

Where is wrong in my code.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put \s in your pattern match [a-zA-Z0-9\s], \s is the space

Answer (score 0):

If there is whitespace in value, it doesn't match the class you've defined.  Try including \s in your character class.  What pattern are you trying to find?

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html